# Cannot get the values out of my get in factory

Tags: angularjs

I have verified that the api is indeed returning the response but I am confused on how to retrieve that response. What am I missing?

Here is my Controller:

```
app.controller('valuesCtrl', function ($scope, valuesFactory) {
    console.log(valuesFactory.values())
});
```

Here is my service:

```
app.factory('valuesFactory', function ($http, $q, $cookieStore) {
    var urlBase = '/api/Values';
    var authHeader = {'Authorization' : 'bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token') }
    var factory = {};

    factory.values = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase, { headers: authHeader }).success(function (response) {
            return response;
        }); 
    }

    return factory;
});
```

Here is what my console log returns:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good idea on a factory, but I would change it to return the promise from `$http.get` rather than values and allow the controller to bind directly to that promise. So your solution simplifies to:

#### Factory

```
app.factory('valuesFactory', function ($http, $q, $cookieStore) {
    var urlBase = '/api/Values';
    var authHeader = {'Authorization' : 'bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token') }
    var factory = {
        fetchValues: function() {
            return $http.get(urlBase, { headers: authHeader });
        }
    }

    return factory;
});
```

#### Controller

```
app.controller('valuesCtrl', function ($scope, valuesFactory) {

    valuesFactory.fetchValues().then(function (data) {
        $scope.values = data;
    }, function (error) {
        $scope.error = 'Contact Support';
    });
});
```

Your current solution is double promising and you can skim it down to just one with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

```
 .success(function (response) {
        return response;
  });
```

That won't work too well.

The success callback is supposed to do something with the response, for example storing it in your model in some way.

The callback has to accept and process the data. Its return value is disregarded (the callback is not called from your code, but asynchronously from Angular when the request is done, and Angular itself has no idea what you want to do with the response).

Comment: I don't understand. The success callback is returning a response.

Comment: The callback cannot return anything. It needs to have a "side-effect" that stores the data from the response somewhere.

Comment: so what is the solution? making a variable and making response equal to that variable then returning that variable?

Answer (score -1):

Changed my code to the following to make it work...

Factory:

```
app.factory('valuesFactory', function ($http, $q, $cookieStore) {
    var urlBase = '/api/Values';
    var authHeader = {'Authorization' : 'bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token') }
    var factory = {};

    factory.values = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase, { headers: authHeader })
           .then(function (response) {
               return response.data;
           }, function (response) {
               return $q.reject(response.data)
           });
    }

    return factory;
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('valuesCtrl', function ($scope, valuesFactory) {
    valuesFactory.values()
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.values = data;
        }, function (error) {
            $scope.error = 'Contact Support';
        });
});
```

Comment: Callbacks are not typically meant to _return_ data. Generally you want to act on or use the data inside of the callbacks. The factory can work that way, but I'd actually allow the controller bind directly to the return value of the $http promise. See my answer for further explanation and example.